# Enable-PSRemoting returns error Unable to check the status of the firewall

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

When I run the command Enable-PSRemoting I get the following error:

PS C:\Windows\system32> Enable-PSRemoting

```
WinRM Quick Configuration
Running command "Set-WSManQuickConfig" to enable remote management of this computer by using the Windows Remote
Management (WinRM) service.
 This includes:
    1. Starting or restarting (if already started) the WinRM service
    2. Setting the WinRM service startup type to Automatic
    3. Creating a listener to accept requests on any IP address
    4. Enabling Windows Firewall inbound rule exceptions for WS-Management traffic (for http only).

Do you want to continue?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): a
WinRM is already set up to receive requests on this computer.
Set-WSManQuickConfig : <f:WSManFault xmlns:f="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/wsmanfault" Code="2"
Machine="localhost"><f:Message><f:ProviderFault provider="Config provider"
path="%systemroot%\system32\WsmSvc.dll"><f:WSManFault xmlns:f="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/wsmanfault"
Code="2" Machine="my_laptop.ad.mydomain.com"><f:Message>Unable to check the status of the firewall.
</f:Message></f:WSManFault></f:ProviderFault></f:Message></f:WSManFault>
At line:69 char:17
+                 Set-WSManQuickConfig -force
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Set-WSManQuickConfig], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WsManError,Microsoft.WSMan.Management.SetWSManQuickConfigCommand
```

From what I've been able to find, this error is supposed to occur when the PC is on a public network. This PC is NOT on a public network but rather is joined to a domain. Running Get-NetConnectionProfile confirms the DomainAuthenticated network status. How do I resolve this and get Enable-PSRemoting to run correctly?

I have a Windows 8 PC running Powershell 4.0.

Comment: What does `(Get-NetConnectionProfile).NetworkCategory` return?  What happens if you use the `-Force` parameter on `Enable-PSRemoting`?  Is your session elevated?  The error message reflects an issue with getting/setting firewall rules.

Comment: (Get-NetConnectionProfile).NetworkCategory returns DomainAuthenticated

Comment: My session is elevated and it's the same result with or without the -Force parameter.

Comment: I also tried turning the firewall off and running the command with it off but it made no difference.

Comment: Have you tested that the command actually failed?  Is your firewall enabled?  Can you verify the rules are in place?  `Get-NetFirewallRule -All | ? Description -like '*5985*'`

Comment: That command returns nothing. I also checked the inbound rules and the WinRM rule is not there.

Comment: I can give you some brief background. I am trying to diagnose an issue with a GPO I created to enabled PSRemoting. In so doing, I used this test machine. I initially ran Enable-PSRemoting and it (Test-WSMan) worked from a remote PC. Then I Applied my GPO as per this instruction set:

https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-powershell-remoting-via-group-policy/

After doing so Test-WSMan failed which confirmed the problem was with my GPO and not AV or something. So I removed the GPO from the system, reran gpupdate /force and the system still wouldn't connect.

Comment: So I figured I'd start from scratch and I ran Disable-PSRemoting which appears to have run successfully and I then reran Enable-PSRemoting and it failed and continues to do so.

Comment: Update: I removed the PC from the domain and rejoined it. Still no joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to set up PSRemoting is through Group Policy.  You'll want to configure the following settings.

Set up the listener:

```
/Computer Configuration
    /Administrative Templates
    /Windows Components
    /Windows Remote Management (WinRM)
    /WinRM Service
        /Allow remote server management through WinRM
            - Enabled
            - IPv4 filter: *
```

Set up firewall rules:

```
/Computer Configuration
    /WindowsSettings
    /Security Settings
    /Windows Firewall with Advanced Security
        /Inbound Rules
            - Type: Port
            - Protocol: TCP
            - Port: 5985
            - Allow the connection
            - Profile: Domain
        /Outbound Rules
            - Type: Port
            - Protocol: TCP
            - Port: 5985
            - Allow the connection
            - Profile: Domain
```

Set up the service:

```
/Computer Configuration
    /WindowsSettings
    /Security Settings
        /System Services
        /Windows Remote Management (WS-Management)
            - Startup mode: Automatic
            > Define this policy setting
                - Service name: WinRM
                - Service action: Start Service
                - Set all Recovery tab actions: Restart the Service
```

After configuring your policy, WinRM should be in working order.  You can validate that remoting is working using the following:

```
# this tests against the FQDN
Test-WSMan -ComputerName [Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($Env:COMPUTERNAME).HostName
```

Comment: The policy settings for WinRM are actually found here:
/Computer Configuration
/Preferences
/Control Panel Settings
/Services

Interestingly, even though the startup mode under the /Security Settings/System Services setting was defined as Automatic, under Control Panel Settings/Services/WinRM it was still defined as No Change as per the instruction set I mentioned prior. I changed that to make the two setting uniform. Will apply this and let you know what happens.

Comment: @user1780242 Might be a difference between OS versions

Comment: *are you sure the outbound port rule is necessary? I was doing some testing with a local configuration on a test machine and disabling it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Outbound may not be necessary.  I know the protocol communicates over 5985 (http)/ 5986 (https), but you're probably right that it's dynamic for outgoing @user1780242

Comment: FYI -- I have figured out the problem I was having. I had placed an IP filter in the WinRM Service settings at /Computer Configuration/Policies/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Windows Remote Management/WinRM Service to restrict to my local subnet and that's what was blocking. When I replaced that with a * it started working. I think I should have done that in the firewall rule instead of in the service configuration. Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: @user1780242 Filters - that'll do it!  Glad to be of service.